# How to disable selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I am trying to disable my selectize dropdown. Initially, upon loading of the page the dropdown should be disabled.  I tried adding disabled to the **select** but I still can choose an item. How can I disable the selectize dropdown?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
document.getElementById("gender").disabled = true;
```

**UPDATE**
I tried using the .disabled() but still not disabling

```
$('#gender').selectize().disable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `disable()` mehtod.

`disable()` Disables user input on the control completely. While disabled, it cannot receive focus.

[selectize.js/api.md at master · selectize/selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: I fixed it hahaha I used $('#gender').selectize()[0].selectize.disable();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are disabling only the select and the options in it

Comment: I am disabling the select how can I disable the options?

Comment: The same way just create an id for your options like this <option id="male">Male</option> and then your javascript should be like document.getElementById("male").disabled= true;

Answer (score 0):

Check ID again , are you sure you are using right Id.
var x = document.getElementById("gender").disabled;
through this check out if a drop-down list is disabled or not.

Try $("#gender").disabled = true;